# Where is inconsistency in this unit test code

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, mapping, restkit

I'm trying to cleanup in unit test I wrote.

```
@implementation CTFUserTests {
    CoreDataService *_service;
    RKObjectManager *_manager;
    CTFAPIMappings *_mapping;
}

- (void)setUp {
    _service = [[CoreDataService alloc] initForUnitTesting];

    _manager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] init];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_service.managedObjectModel];
    _manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleIdentifier stringByAppendingString:@"Tests"]];
    [RKTestFixture setFixtureBundle:bundle];

    _mapping = [[CTFAPIMappings alloc] initWithManager:_manager];

    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown {
    _service = nil;
    _manager = nil;
    [super tearDown];
}
```

Here is method which return `RKEntityMapping`:

```
- (RKEntityMapping *)simpleUserMapping {
    RKEntityMapping *userMapping =
    [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([CTFUser class]) inManagedObjectStore:_mapping.manager.managedObjectStore];
    [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[_mapping userMappingDict]];
    return userMapping;
}
```

Here is the test:

```
- (void)testUserResponseMApping {
    id parsedJSON = [RKTestFixture parsedObjectWithContentsOfFixture:@"user-response.json"];

    /// Configure mapping
    RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [self simpleUserMapping];

    RKMappingTest *test = [RKMappingTest testForMapping:userMapping sourceObject:parsedJSON destinationObject:nil];
    test.managedObjectContext = _service.managedObjectContext;

    RKPropertyMappingTestExpectation *usernameExpectation =
    [RKPropertyMappingTestExpectation expectationWithSourceKeyPath:@"username" destinationKeyPath:@"username" value:@"tomkowz12"];
    [test addExpectation:usernameExpectation];
    [test verify];
```

And here all is ok. Test passes.
But what I want is to create some class where I can define and return all mappings needed to make calls to the server. It's sounds as singleton with mappings. So here it is.

```
@interface CTFAPIMappings : NSObject

@property (readonly) RKObjectManager *manager;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
+ (void)setSharedInstance:(CTFAPIMappings *)sharedInstance;
- (instancetype)initWithManager:(RKObjectManager *)manager;
- (RKEntityMapping *)userMapping;
- (NSDictionary *)userMappingDict;
@end
```

Implementation of `-userMapping` method looks the same like above method `-simpleUserMapping` in unit test class. As you see above method `-simpleUserMapping` uses `_mapping` object which is type of `CTFAPIMappings`. So the same is in method of `CTFAPIMappings` but with self instead of `_mapping`.

```
@implementation CTFAPIMappings
…
- (RKEntityMapping *)userMapping {
    RKEntityMapping *userMapping =
    [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([CTFUser class]) inManagedObjectStore:_manager.managedObjectStore];
    [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[self userMappingDict]];
    return userMapping;
}
```

`CTFAPIMappings` object is initialized with `RKObjectManager` initialized in `-setUp` method. So it's the same `RKObjectManager` as in test method. And the problem is in `testUserResponseMapping` method when I replace:

```
    RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [self simpleUserMapping];
```

with:

```
    RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [_mapping userMapping];
```

And test crashes on method `-performMapping` in `RKMappingTest` class on line:

```
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"%p: failed with error: %@\n%@ during mapping from %@ to %@ with mapping %@",
```

And crash log looks as following:

```
<unknown>:0: error: -[CTFUserTests testUserResponseMApping] : 0x8d96f30: failed with error: (null)
RKMappingTest Expectations: (
    "map 'username' to 'username' with __NSCFConstantString value 'tomkowz12'"
)
Events: (
) during mapping from <CFBasicHash 0x8d7ef90 [0x2267ec8]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x8d70d00 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "password"} = <CFString 0x8d70d20 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "password123"}
    2 : <CFString 0x8d76bb0 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "username"} = <CFString 0x8d76600 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "tomkowz12"}
    3 : <CFString 0x8d7d160 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "location"} = <CFArray 0x8d7ef70 [0x2267ec8]>{type = immutable, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <CFNumber 0x8faef40 [0x2267ec8]>{value = +10, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    1 : <CFNumber 0x8d7d180 [0x2267ec8]>{value = +20, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
)}
    4 : <CFString 0x8d94f50 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "email"} = <CFString 0x8d76620 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "tmk.szlc@gmail.com"}
    6 : <CFString 0x8d92860 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "nick"} = <CFString 0x8d7d140 [0x2267ec8]>{contents = "black_lord"}
}
 to (null) with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x8d7a8d0 objectClass=CTFUser propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8d7a300 password => password>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8d732b0 username => username>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8d77fe0 location => location>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8d95db0 email => email>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8d7ce60 nick => nick>"
)>
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0211c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01e9f8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0211c3bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   Capture The FlagTests               0x098f08ab -[RKMappingTest performMapping] + 1067
    4   Capture The FlagTests               0x098f0f53 -[RKMappingTest verify] + 99
    5   Capture The FlagTests               0x09801e35 -[CTFUserTests testUserResponseMApping] + 517
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x02110d1d __invoking___ + 29
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x02110c2a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 362
    8   XCTest                              0x201032bf -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 212
    9   XCTest                              0x2010338d -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 111
    10  XCTest                              0x2010417c -[XCTest run] + 82
    11  XCTest                              0x20102a44 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    12  XCTest                              0x2010417c -[XCTest run] + 82
    13  XCTest                              0x20102a44 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    14  XCTest                              0x2010417c -[XCTest run] + 82
    15  XCTest                              0x20102a44 -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 139
    16  XCTest                              0x2010417c -[XCTest run] + 82
    17  XCTest                              0x20105aa1 +[XCTestProbe runTests:] + 183
    18  Foundation                          0x01ad612c __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x020dabd6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x020da5bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x020c2628 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x020c1ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x020c18db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x03ae29e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x03ae2809 GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x00c0dd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  Capture The Flag                    0x0000a27d main + 141
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0275a70d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x00000008 0x0 + 8
)
```

I spent with this case about 4 hours and don't see any things I missed. For me all is ok, but test not passes. What is wrong with my cleanup? I missed something?

Thank you in advance.

***Edit***

I add below test for equality `RKOBjectManager` created in test with injected to `CTFAPIMappings` instance.

```
- (void)testInstanceShouldHaveTheSameManagerAndStoreAsInjected {
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] init];
    RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:_service.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [store createManagedObjectContexts];

    objectManager.managedObjectStore = store;

    CTFAPIMappings *mappings = [[CTFAPIMappings alloc] initWithManager:objectManager];
    XCTAssertNotNil(mappings, @"");
    XCTAssertNotNil(mappings.manager, @"");
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(mappings.manager, objectManager, @"");
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(mappings.manager.managedObjectStore, objectManager.managedObjectStore, @"");
}
```

And here is some simple test which check equality of two mappings (objects are equal):

```
RKEntityMapping *localCharacterMapping = [self userMapping];
RKEntityMapping *mappingsCharacterMapping = [_mappings userMapping];

XCTAssertEqualObjects(localCharacterMapping.entity, mappingsCharacterMapping.entity, @"");
XCTAssertEqualObjects(localCharacterMapping.persistentStore, mappingsCharacterMapping.persistentStore, @"");

NSLog(@"local = %@", localCharacterMapping);
NSLog(@"mappi = %@", mappingsCharacterMapping);
```

And log:

```
2013-12-07 15:12:07.094 Capture The Flag[27712:70b] local = <RKEntityMapping:0x8ee9ac0 objectClass=CTFUser propertyMappings=(
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e91c00 password => password>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8ebeb50 username => username>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8ecb830 location => location>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e94730 email => email>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8ec5d90 nick => nick>",
"<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x8eebef0 characters => characters>"
)>
2013-12-07 15:12:07.096 Capture The Flag[27712:70b] mappi = <RKEntityMapping:0x8eec060 objectClass=CTFUser propertyMappings=(
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8eed020 password => password>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e8a910 username => username>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8eb5a30 location => location>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e86620 email => email>",
"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x8e92490 nick => nick>",
"<RKRelationshipMapping: 0x8eee3d0 characters => characters>"
)>
```

Comment: Did you debug the mapping creation and usage to check everything exists? You set the store?

Comment: Mapping in working version is the same as in not working version. I don't know why when mapping is returned from other class there is a problem :/ Look at this two methods which returns userMapping - in both test class method and in CTFMappings class there are used the same `_manager` (`RKObjectManager`) and the same `RKManagedObjectStore`.

Comment: Did you actually check the manager and store being used?

Comment: Yes, this manager is working, It's the same manager. I create manager and store, initialized `CTFAPIMappings` instance and with accessors I use `XCTEqualObjects` macro, compared to original store and manager and there are the same.

Comment: @Wain, I added unit test for checking equality of `RKOBjectManager` created in test with this from accessor. Passed.

Comment: I added additional unit tests and log.

Comment: It's working on mac in the office. When I back to home I will check cocoapods and pods version and retest it.

Comment: Ok I checked that. The problem was in Cocoapods. In home I'd 0.22 and in office I've got 0.27. After update to 0.28 and after update pods all works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I checked that. The problem was in Cocoapods. In home I'd 0.22 and in office I've got 0.27. After update to 0.28 and after update pods all works correctly. – Tomasz Szulc just now edit